# TypeError: string indices must be integers when filtering values in a JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

```
x = { "people": [{ "owner": "bob", "petname": "fido", "species": "dog", "size": "chunky"}, {"owner": "mary","petname": "marvin","species": "cat","size": "cat"}]}
    y = json.dumps(x)
    z = json.loads(y)
    for i in z:
        if i["owner"] == "bob":
            print(i['petname'])
            break
```

The goal of this code is to return the pet name while giving the owner's name. For example, output "fido" by giving the owners name "bob"

However all I get is `TypeError: string indices must be integers`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why convert a dictionary to json, when it is easier to surf through the dictionary?

Comment: Well, this is testing for an eventual API that's obviously going to be dealing with jsons, I need to learn how to navigate and process a json.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are iterating the base `dictionary` instead of iteration the `list` under `people`

Iterate over `z["people"]` which contains a `list`, instead of iterating `z`
**Solution**

```py
x = { "people": [{ "owner": "bob", "petname": "fido", "species": "dog", "size": "chunky"}, {"owner": "mary","petname": "marvin","species": "cat","size": "cat"}]}
    y = json.dumps(x)
    z = json.loads(y)
    for i in z["people"]:
        if i["owner"] == "bob":
            print(i['petname'])
            break
```

Also, I don't see any need of using

```py
y = json.dumps(x)
z = json.loads(y)
```

You can simply use the base dictionary `x`

```py
for i in x["people"]:
    if i["owner"] == "bob":
       print(i['petname'])
       break
```

Comment: json is required if the API data is received as a string by the user

Answer (score 1):

Reason for error: You are iterating over keys of the dictionary. So initially `i` was `people` which is a string. You were trying `i["owner"]` which throws an error as `i` was a string.

`x` is actually a dictionary, you can directly access it without using `json` package.

Code:

```
x = { "people": [{ "owner": "bob", "petname": "fido", "species": "dog", "size": "chunky"}, {"owner": "mary","petname": "marvin","species": "cat","size": "cat"}]}
people = x["people"]
for i in people:
    if i["owner"] == "bob":
        print(i['petname'])
        break
```

If you need `JSON`:

```
import json
x = { "people": [{ "owner": "bob", "petname": "fido", "species": "dog", "size": "chunky"}, {"owner": "mary","petname": "marvin","species": "cat","size": "cat"}]}
y = json.dumps(x)
z = json.loads(y)
people = z["people"]
for i in people:
    if i["owner"] == "bob":
        print(i['petname'])
        break
```

Output:

```
fido
```